# How to create a dataframe with rows name

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a dataframe as given below and then later I need to add values as per rows and column.Can anybody please tell me how can i do this?

```
    ColA  ColB  ColC
```

Name     2     21    10

Roll   4       67    21

Comment: what have you tried and what's not working? there are a ton of tutorials helping you get started with pandas. try them out before asking for help - see the guide on [how to ask a question](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index= ['Name','Roll'], columns=['ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC'])

df.loc['Name','ColA'] = val
```